# How to fix this error

Tags: macos, terminal, osx-mountain-lion

When I open terminal system shown error below

> -bash: /etc/profile.d/sm.sh: No such file or directory 
>   -bash: /etc/profile.d/rvm.sh: No such file or directory

[image]

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Looks like you used to have `rvm` or something, and then removed it?  Anyway, remove the offending files from `/etc/profile.d` and you should be fine.

Comment: yep !!!

I have sovled by comment to line in (/etc/profile)
#source /etc/profile.d/sm.sh
#source /etc/profile.d/rvm.sh